# Absolute path string has characters that break URL

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to get an absolute path and run a local HTML file in a webbrowser control.

```
        string exeFile = (new System.Uri(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;
        string exeDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(exeFile);
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(exeDir, "HTML\\index.html");

        this.webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri(fullPath, System.UriKind.Absolute);
```

THis is not working because full path ends up being:

c:\users\tunnelld2\documents\visual%20studio%202012\Projects\qTab2\qTab2\bin\Debug\HTML\index.html

I have checked multiple times and the path is correct. The issue appears to be this:

visual%20studio%202012

If I manually use the string: "c:\users\tunnelld2\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\qTab2\qTab2\bin\Debug\HTML\index.html"

it works fine. How do I remove the %20 from my string so that I can render the HTML page

Answer (score 1):

```
string exeFile = (new System.Uri(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase, true)).AbsolutePath;
```

You can specify a bool to not escape the URL.